# How to serialize a derived class in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, json, serialization

I created a custom control in XAML, and added some custom properties as well. Now, I want to serialize it to JSON if possible. Here is (essentially) what I have:

```
public partial class MyCustomClass : UserControl
{
    public Dictionary<char, int[]> ValueMap;
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And in the code that handles serialization:

```
public static string Serialize(object objectToSerialize)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
          new DataContractJsonSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, objectToSerialize);
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms)) 
          return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

However, `serializer.WriteObject(ms, objectToSerialize);` throws

`System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException`:

> Consider marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute, and
>   marking all of its members you want
>   serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.
>   Alternatively, you can ensure that the
>   type is public and has a parameterless
>   constructor - all public members of
>   the type will then be serialized, and
>   no attributes will be required."

Now, when I do add those attributes to the `MyCustomClass`, I of course get the same exception, only this time for `System.Windows.UIElement` instead of `MyCustomClass`.

So, is there a way to serialize my custom derived class with the existing serialization method, or should I just write a custom serialization methods for `MyCustomClass`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are better off implementing IXmlSerializable here, as you really don't want to indiscriminately serialize everything in the base class (and I don't believe you can, quite frankly).

Rather, implement IXmlSerializable on MyCustomClass, and then the DataContractJsonSerializer will be able to use that implementation to serialize to/from JSON.

Comment: Wow, I never would have expected that IXmlSerializable would work for a DataContractJsonSerializer, but it does. The first thing I thought of was ISerializable, but apparently it's not supported in Silverlight.